# Entity Framework 4

Tags: entity-framework

Where can I download this?

I have VS2010 RTM but it does not come with it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework 4 **is** part of .NET 4 / Visual Studio 2010 - no need to download anything, it's in the package.

In VS 2010, you should be able to add a new item to a project and pick "ADO.NET Entity Framework" (from the "Data" tab).

[image]

This will add an *.edmx file to your project, which is the Entity Framework - the visual designer, the code generation behind the scenes - all of it.